# Google Sparsehash - understanding keys

Tags: c++, hashmap

I'm trying to get an understanding of Google Sparsehash library.
Following the example from http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/sparse_hash_map.html, it compiled and worked nicely.

However, when I started changing things, I got confused. I changed the example to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sparsehash/sparse_hash_map>

using google::sparse_hash_map;      // namespace where class lives by default
using std::cout;
using std::hash;  // or __gnu_cxx::hash, or maybe tr1::hash, depending on your OS

using namespace std;

struct eqstr
{
    bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const
    {
        return (s1 == s2) || (s1 && s2 && strcmp(s1, s2) == 0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    sparse_hash_map<const char*, int, hash<const char*> > months;

    char april[] = "april";
    months["january"] = 31;
    months["february"] = 28;
    months["march"] = 31;
    months[april] = 30;
    months["may"] = 31;
    months["june"] = 30;
    months["july"] = 31;
    months["august"] = 31;
    months["september"] = 30;
    months["october"] = 31;
    months["november"] = 30;
    months["december"] = 31;

    cout << "april     -> " << months[april] << endl;

    april[0] = 'd';
    cout << april << endl;
    cout << "dpril     -> " << months[april] << endl;
    cout << "count dpril:  " << months.count(april) << endl;
```

and the results are:

```
april     -> 30
dpril
dpril     -> 30
count dpril:  1
```

I'm not sure I understand this correctly. When I changed a letter in the `april` variable, it shouldn't have found it as a key. The count should have been 0. 
If I do

```
cout << "april     -> " << months["april"] << endl;
```

The result is `april     -> 0`, even though `"april"` is in the map.

Am I having a completely wrong understanding of hash maps? It seems to me as instead of using the value `"april"`, it uses the memory address of the variable `april` when inserting and looking it up.

Any and all clarifications would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the hash map, you say that the key is a *pointer*, not a string or whatever else the pointer points to. So you can in fact change the contents of the `april` array to whatever you want, as it's the pointer to `april` that is the key.

Then when you use the string literal `"april"` as key, it's the pointer to that literal that is added as a new key.